# How to ping an IP in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, ping

I am writing `Windows Phone` applications which needs to stay connected to the server (precisely speaking windows service application). I want to ping server, llet's say, every 1 second to catch disconnections, etc.

In addition I have to point that I am using `Windows Phone SilverLight 8.1` project (I can't do this in normal `Windows Phone 8.1` because of `Socket` class that is not included)

The fastest way I have found so far is to use `Ping` class from `System.Net.NetworkInformation`. The thing is that visual studio says there's no `Ping` class.

Ok, MSDN documentation doesn't mention `Windows Phone SilverLight 8.1` as supported platform. But When I created test `Windows Phone 8.1` project visual again said that `Ping` doesn't exist.

[Here is MSDN documentation page:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

and here are supported platforms:

> Platforms:
>   **Windows Phone 8.1**, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)

**Why can't I use Ping class?**

If that isn't my fault (like missing assembly, etc.), **how can I "ping" my server application in different way?**

Comment: I doubt pinging is the proper way to maintain your connection. Why wouldn't you realize the disconnection at the next attempt to communicate?

Comment: I am not sure if it's proper way. I want to stream video over UDP and I wanted to ensure connection status with ping (for instance to resume sending/receiving UDP packages after reconnect).

Comment: Does creating the UDP connection not give you a connection status?

Comment: I think the information provided in Polish version is incorrect. with the same link I just changed Pl-pl to en-US and the phone and windows 8 version gone :)

Comment: I would never thought about it... That's really weird. I can't even see `Supported platforms` section in english version. I guess I'll have to write it myself. Thanks for great tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for wrong System.Net.Information implementation. The one you linked is desktop .NET version. For right one you need to look at Silverlight .NET class library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew4thdx(v=VS.95).aspx

Ping is not available at Silverlight, but you can implement own ping command with Windows.Network.Sockets:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/03/19/datagram-socket-communication-in-windows-phone-8.aspx

Comment: It's all true. I already know that `Silverlight` doesn't have such functionality (btw thanks for the above link, I surely try to write this), as I mention in first post.

Now I am curious why doesn't it work in `Windows Phone 8.1`? Documentation says it is supported.

Comment: According to @Muhammad Saifullah post `Windows Phone 8.1` isn't supported too. I will have to make my own Ping class. Thanks for link again :)